# strerror with MinGW-w64

Tags: c, windows, mingw-w64

Take this simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
main (void)
{
  printf ("ERROR %d %s\n", ETIMEDOUT, strerror (ETIMEDOUT));
  return 0;
}
```

If you compile it with Cygwin gcc it runs fine

```
$ gcc a.c

$ ./a
ERROR 116 Connection timed out
```

If you compile it with MinGW-w64 gcc it does not give proper error message

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc a.c

$ ./a
ERROR 138 Unknown error
```

How can I get MinGW-w64 to put correct error message?

Comment: Some additional tidbits about `ETIMEDOUT`: at least one of my MinGW installations defines it to be `10060` (the same as `WSAETIMEDOUT`) instead of `138` if it's not already defined. I think this is because the legacy `winsock.h` used to do that (but doesn't anymore).  Boost will define it to be `9938` if the compiler's `cerrno` doesn't already define it - which didn't start happening in MSVC until VS2010. So, I'd say you might consider yourself a little lucky you even get the program to compile.

Comment: @MichaelBurr - WinSock  borrowed WSAETIMEDOUT (10060) from Berkeley Sockets according to http://www.sockets.com/err_lst1.htm#WSAETIMEDOUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ETIMEDOUT` seems to be a [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html) extension to the ISO C standard errno.h. Cygwin has better support for POSIX than MinGW. A bug report about `ETIMEDOUT` for mingw32 was opened and closed in [2007](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=102435&aid=1750842&group_id=2435).

One option is to use the GNU Portability Library ([Gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/)). It provides a POSIX-like [errno.h](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/errno_002eh.html) and [strerror()/strerror_override()](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/MODULES.html#ansic_sup) .